# Argument not Optional Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a sheet to extract data from a list of job openings that I need to sort and filter by location and by BU. I need the code to count the number of openings then pass that information back to the main sub to use in creating additional pages and to loop the sub. I keep getting the above error in this segment. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub Organize_Data()

    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim C As Integer

    Worksheets.Add().Name = "Calculations"
    Find_Unit
    Find_Locations
    Count_BU_Data
    Count_Country_Data
    Count_Raw_Data
End Sub

Function Count_BU_Data(A As Integer)

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3", Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UDF:

```
Function Count_BU_Data(A As Integer)
```

Takes an argument (`A As Integer`) which you haven't specified as being an *Optional* argument. You call the function from your other routine without supplying this argument:

```
Sub Organize_Data()

    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim C As Integer

    Worksheets.Add().Name = "Calculations"
    Find_Unit
    Find_Locations
    Count_BU_Data    '// <~~ No argument passed to function.
    Count_Country_Data
    Count_Raw_Data
End Sub
```

Hence the 'Argument not optional' error.

Seeing as that function doesn't appear to actually use the argument, you can either remove it from the function header:

```
Function Count_BU_Data() As Long '// Note I've included a return value...
```

Or make it an optional argument

```
Function Count_BU_Data(Optional A As Integer) As Long
```

You can also specify a default value if the optional argument isn't supplied

```
Function Count_BU_Data(Optional A As Integer = 1) As Long
```

Comment: How would you suggest fixing it?

Comment: Also, what is the point of this function? It doesn't return a value or change anything so it's of no value to your code...

Comment: I am trying to get it to return a value. That is what I am trying to figure out how to do. I am pretty new to VBA so am basically just blundering along.

Comment: It's a bit too long winded to go into the workings of a UDF in the comments here, but once you've hit 20 rep [join this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge) and I'll be happy to go through it with you

Comment: I saw you appeared in the chat room, if you can actually see what's being said I can explain it while you're in there even though you can't post anything if you haven't got 20+ rep

Comment: I had to head out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries, when you hit 20 rep just ping me in that room :)

Comment: I just figured out my problem. I was trying to run it as a separate program instead of in the main sub. I moved it to the main sub and it works great. Thanks for the help.